# will not putting my ssh key in ~/.ssh/ folder prevent people from accessing my laptop?

Tags: ssh

I did something dumb today and my private ssh key was revealed on the internet.
Fortunately, I haven't added any ssh keys that were generated into the default ~/.ssh/ folder.
I generated them on my desktop folder and they are still there.
If I just delete these two files (private key) and (public key) files, would an anonymous person holding the key I uploaded not be able to access my laptop via ssh?
This might seem like a very basic question but it's hard to find it on the internet..
Thanks!

Comment: No. To use it, it has to be deployed on a computer that has an ssh server running (public key has to be appended into  the .ssh/authorized_keys file in a user's home on such a computer).

Comment: @zmb Thank you so much! Now I feel relieved :D